# How best to welcome new users?

Tags: discussion

This post is a reminder of the review queues and to ask a question: *How best to welcome new users?*

Here is how to find the review queues:

[image]

If you can see the icon that I expanded in the image, you should have enough reputation to participate.

Assuming one reviews something in the *First Post* review queue what is the best way to welcome a new user?

---

It doesn't seem like there are many new users who started using the review queues since I posted this 17 days ago.  Here is the current screenshot of the close and first posts queues:

[image]

I was thinking perhaps I was getting in the way of others using these queues by reviewing too quickly, but apparently not. So I will continue reviewing the close and first posts.  My last review on these two queues was at least 30 days ago.

Comment: Say "Welcome to Philosophy!" :)

Comment: @JosephWeissman Good phrase. I just used it for the first time.

Answer (score 3):

> How best to welcome new users?

By not tolerating or engaging in biased removals of a new user's comments, especially when the incendiary ones posted at him by some "veteran" in the site are left intact. It is disappointing that the moderators in Philosophy SE consent to these biased, selective removals.

I recently posted few comments to [this question](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/59265/how-could-an-eternal-god-know-that-he-is-eternal) and then an [answer](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/59265/how-could-an-eternal-god-know-that-he-is-eternal/59277#59277). User jobermark got very hostile, pretending I said something terrible in the comments. I replied trying to set the record straight because no user (regardless of his high SE "reputation") should heckle other contributors, let alone by mischaraterizing them. One moderator eventually moved the comments to [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87742/discussion-on-question-by-breakskater-how-does-god-know-that-he-is-eternal).

Hours later, I started noticing that many of my comments (and only my comments, not jobermark's) were removed from the post. Luckily the chat still displays what I wrote, which helps showing that the scandalous remarks by that user are unwarranted. I have a screenshot of the chat (available upon request) in case someone else removes my comments also from the chat.

Once the moderator created the chat, the aforementioned user resumed his harangue now by posting multiple comments at my answer. There, I explained to him why I was going to ignore his subsequent comments. Within few minutes he posted two additional comments (one of them including the direction "GO AWAY", in uppercase). Apparently, even he realized that he was crossing the line and removed these two.

Since then, somebody has removed also my comment [to jobermark] that I posted on my answer (screenshot available), which gives the inaccurate impression that I am "persuaded" by that user's latest rant.

I understand that every site has trolls, but the bias and/or selective leniency that the Philosophy SE moderators convey on distasteful incidents like this contradicts the purported concern of making new users feel welcome. I participate in other SE sites, and I can attest to their respective moderators' higher sense of fairness.

Comment: I am not familiar with the exchange you had recently. However, I get my share of people who disagree with me. This is what I do: (1) I do not get angry. (2) I do not respond. (3) If the person says anything that appears unfriendly I flag the comment for the moderators to deal with.  This makes it easy for the moderators to deal with the issue because they only have to deal with one person's comments, not two people exchanging comments.  Best wishes.

Comment: @FrankHubeny That is the best approach in most situations, but sometimes a mod might dismiss our flag as unimportant, and we end up unduly prejudiced (apropos of "reputation") with respect to an OP by some troll. In this incident, one mod moved the comments to chat, another one seemed aware of the comments (see the exclamation sign in the last sentence of his meta [answer](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3850/arent-non-religious-posts-about-gods-epistemology-on-topic/3851#3851)), and neither reacted to the heckling.Then I doubt flagging would have made any difference there.

Comment: That happens to me as well. Not all of my flags are accepted. However, there are other things to do here. Post a different question or answer or read and up-vote other posts. Focus on something else and have a good time learning philosophy in the process.

Comment: @IñakiViggers: I deleted the comments of jobermark now. He has a history of flagging other user's comments in comment threads he himself caused to derail by inappropriate language. We will look more carefully into flags like that.

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking Thank you. I appreciate the follow-up as well as your noticing of the issue. I was advised that "*if the other comments had been flagged* (that is, by me) *for removal, they would have been, too*", but to me incidents like that are not a matter of flagging back so as to get even with that user. Thanks again.